# Edit username of old Git commits

Tags: git, git-commit

My global Git config had the wrong username and email address and I forgot to overwrite it in a specific project.

Now there are many commits and pushes done with the wrong username.

Is there any possibility to revert this or do I have to completely destroy the project and make it new?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script from github: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info

This script is difficult to use if you've shared the code with other people, but if not it should work well.